# Can I access inner_hits total from within script?

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I am returning grouped products via `has_child` query und would like to boost groups with more products.
I planned to wrap a function_score query around to modify `_score` but so far have not found a way to access the total value.

```
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "script_score": {
            _score * ACCESS_INNER_HITS_TOTAL_HERE;
            "
        },
        "query": {
            "has_child": {...
```

How else could I achieve this with ElasticSearch 2.2? (score_mode `sum` seems too strong)